# Why can't I set an object passed down to a function but can set it's children?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to code a function that lets the user upload their local JSON file as a `save` object replacing it:

```js
function uploadJSON(importObject, importID) {
  //{...}
  reader.onload = function () {
    importObject = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    uploadAnchorNode.remove();
  }
  //{...}
}
```

When I call `uploadJSON(save, "someid")` and then `console.log(save)` it shows the old save.

If I set the 4th line to:

```js
save = JSON.parse(reader.result);
//or:
importObject.settings = JSON.parse(reader.result).settings;
importObject.game = JSON.parse(reader.result).game;
importObject.errors = JSON.parse(reader.result).errors;
```

it works perfectly.

Why can't I just set the whole object like this: `importObject = JSON.parse(reader.result);`?

Comment: Please provide a [example] so that we can see the exact problem reproduced here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you receive a *reference* to the object.

Imagine this situation:

```
var foo = {                // now "foo" contains a reference to an object
    data: "something"
};

var bar = foo;             // now "bar" contains a new reference to the same object

bar = {};                  // overwriting "bar" will not change "foo"
```

If you don't find that surprising (and there is no reason why you should), then the following should not surprise you either, because it's exactly the same thing.

```
var foo = {                // now "foo" contains a reference to an object
    data: "something"
};

function test1(bar) {      // now "bar" is a reference to an object
    bar = {};              // overwriting "bar" will not change any other variables that reference the same object
}

test1(foo);
```

That you can change *properties* of an object, and then all references to that object will show the same state should not be a surprise, either, since the object only exists once.